# mediawiki 500 internal error when visit the home page

Tags: mediawiki

```
MediaWiki suddenly came with 500 internal error 

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getCode() on
null in /var/www/wiki/includes/user/User.php:1578 Stack trace: #0
/var/www/wiki/includes/user/User.php(5243): User::getDefaultOptions()
#1 /var/www/wiki/includes/user/User.php(2859): User->loadOptions() #2 /var/www/wiki/includes/context/RequestContext.php(364):
User->getOption('language') #3
/var/www/wiki/includes/Message.php(380): RequestContext->getLanguage()
#4 /var/www/wiki/includes/Message.php(1257): Message->getLanguage() #5 /var/www/wiki/includes/Message.php(842): Message->fetchMessage() #6
/var/www/wiki/includes/Message.php(934): Message->toString('text') #7
/var/www/wiki/includes/exception/MWExceptionRenderer.php(254):
Message->text() #8
/var/www/wiki/includes/exception/MWExceptionRenderer.php(358):
MWExceptionRenderer::msg('dberr-again', 'Try waiting a f...') #9
/var/www/wiki/includes/exception/MWExceptionRenderer.php(52):
MWExceptionRenderer::reportOutageHTML(Object(Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBConnectionError))
#10 /var/www/wiki/includes/exception/MWExce in /var/www/wiki/includes/user/User.php on line 1578
```

Comment: Something must have gone wrong in the initialization, but a single stack trace is not all that useful in describing the problem.

Comment: I'm receiving pretty much the same error message. How can I get more information about whats causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a bug that might happen if you have multiple install attempts and the mysql.user is still there. I had the same problem today.

I have filed the bug as:
https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T177768

the Problem went away after reinstalling with the following steps:

```
dropping database
removing user from mysql.users
strangely the "user exists" error still appeared on installation
granting access rights was therefore necessary on the mysql database.
```